# Can Spark connect be use on top of YARN setup?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to connect to an existing Spark cluster using yarn through spark-connect ?

Let's say Yarn is running on server1 and server2
I start spark connect on server1 using yarn

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --jars x,y,... --master yarn
```

(seems okay)
then I tried to reach this spark connect on yarn

```
pyspark --remote sc://server1
```

Seems to work too...
But a soon as I try to use a custom python function (from my jupyterlab), it failed du to:
*org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan; local class incompatible: stream classdesc ...
*
Does anybody successfully started spark-connect on YARN ? I can not find any documentation at all.

spark connect to 1 node without using yarn worked. But I am not able to use all nodes in this configuration, nor HA ...

Thanks

Apache Spark 3.5
YARN 3.3.6

spark-connect on 1 node standalone without YARN: okay
spark-connect on a YARN cluster: failed